# Yamaha P115 Aux out issue

Tags: piano, digital-piano, mixing

So I have a Yamaha P115 and I want to be able to mix the output with a YouTube video or some other reference. I've got myself a simple 4-channel audio mixer (r/http://amzn.eu/d/aP0TXbI) to try and do this. I've connected it up to the aux out of the piano and plugged some headphones into the output but sadly I'm not getting anything through the headphones, the sound still plays through the piano speakers.

I had a look at the manual for the P115 (https://jp.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/8/333278/p115_en_om_b0.pdf) which states on page 23 that "When the instrument’s sound is output to an external device, first turn on the power to the instrument, then to the external device. Reverse this order when you turn the power off." but this has not helped.

I'm a bit of a noob with this stuff so apologies if I'm being stupid. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Just realised that if I whack the volume up on the input of the mixer I can just about hear the piano through the headphones. Do I have the wrong leads? I am using these: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B003L6ZPQ4/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 23 of the Piano manual shows the correct way to connect an external device; but from your description, it sounds like you're doing that OK.

I believe the problem is that Behringer mixer. It's not the correct tool for the job you want to do. The output from that mixer is intended to be fed into a power amp, not a set of headphones. That explains why you can hear very little sound through it; the output is just far too low. Just because your headphones may fit into the output jack, doesn't mean they'll work.

To stay in the same price range, look at a small five channel mixer which has a dedicated headphones output - that'll do exactly what you need to do (and most also have RCA tape inputs for music from other devices).

Comment: Thanks Pete. I think I just about came to the same conclusion whilst doing some research. I think I have indeed bought the wrong sort of mixer. Would something like this be a better choice? http://amzn.eu/d/6rdBAAZ. It has a dedicated phones output so I'm hoping so! I also read somewhere that I could keep what I have bit also get a headphone amp, something like this - http://amzn.eu/d/8lmAiqK. Is that also a viable option?

Comment: Andy, don't waste money on the headphone amp. Those are designed to take one input, and give you five headphone outputs. It's useful if you play with friends, but you'll gain nothing but a mess of cables if you put it into your existing solution. Buy the 5-channel mixer you're looking at. It's still a basic model, but it's more expandable and useful.

Comment: I bought a Yamaha MG06 6 channel mixer which has independent amplifier and headphone outputs.  Something like that should work well for you.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm returning the MX400 and have ordered the Behringer Xenyx 502 which should arrive tomorrow. I expect that will solve the problem. Will accept the answer once all confirmed and working :)